# Move zero price products to the end of the catalog product list (magento)

Tags: magento

I need to push zero price products to the end of the catalog product list no matter which sort order is chosen.

This code do the same thing, but with "out of stock" products.

```
<?php
class Test_Ext_Model_Catalog_Observer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer
{
    public function rebuildCollection($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();     
        $collection = $event->getCollection();

        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('_inventory_table'=>$collection->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
            "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id", 
            array('is_in_stock', 'manage_stock'));

        $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
            'stock_down',
            '(CASE WHEN (((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 1) 
            AND (_inventory_table.is_in_stock = 1))
            OR  ((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 0) 
            AND (1 - _inventory_table.manage_stock + _inventory_table.is_in_stock >= 1))) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
            array());
        $collection->getSelect()->order('stock_down DESC');

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code right between $collection->getSelect()->order('stock_down DESC'); and return $collection;

```
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
    'zero_price_down',
    '(CASE WHEN (price_index.price = 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)',
    array());
$collection->getSelect()->order('zero_price_down DESC');
```

And you get method which move zero price and out of stock products to the end of the catalog product list no matter which sort order is chosen:

```
public function rebuildCollection($observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();     
    $collection = $event->getCollection();

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('_inventory_table'=>$collection->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
        "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id", 
        array('is_in_stock', 'manage_stock'));

    $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
        'stock_down',
        '(CASE WHEN (((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 1) 
        AND (_inventory_table.is_in_stock = 1))
        OR  ((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 0) 
        AND (1 - _inventory_table.manage_stock + _inventory_table.is_in_stock >= 1))) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
        array());
    $collection->getSelect()->order('stock_down DESC');

    $collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
        'zero_price_down',
        '(CASE WHEN (price_index.price = 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)',
        array());
    $collection->getSelect()->order('zero_price_down DESC');

    return $collection;
}
```